# Eclipse issue with Ctrl-Click feature

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7

I have an issue with my eclipse. I use Ctrl-Click to navigate to a method declaration, It just show the content of that method on editor rather than the entire java source file. Please see the attachment.

I have tried to restore default configuration of eclipse but nothing change.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Did you install a new plugin? Tried restarting it?

Comment: No, Everything works fine yesterday. I didn't install any new plugin from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yeah. I have found my root cause. It is eclipse workspace's issue. Just delete the `.metadata` folder inside workspace folder and restart eclipse. Now it works fine again.

Comment: Great! I generally restart eclipse with `-clean` first to see if it fixes it.